# VS Code Intellisense not showing suggestions in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

Intellisense in VS Code only shows the previously used keywords and identifiers(in the current program) and not suggesting the new ones.[The autocomplete only suggests the previously used keywords and identifiers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/no8sY.png)

Comment: This could have been a Super User question. If only there was a question..

Comment: Using the right tool: From Ms [FAQ](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/FAQ), Vs code is not for programming it's more a little open source editor for quick editting and debug. If you are writting code in it and find it inconveniant.. Use Community instead. It's free.

Answer (score 6):

Disabling the c# extension then re-enabling and restarting the vs code solves this issue for me

Answer (score 1):

This will help you buddy.

C# language support is an optional install from the Marketplace.
You can install it from within VS Code by searching for 'C#' in the Extensions view (Ctrl+Shift+X) or if you already have a project with C# files, VS Code will prompt you to install the extension as soon as you open a C# file.

Visual Studio Code uses the power of Roslyn and OmniSharp to offer an enhanced C# experience. 
So to summarize, you will need two things to do dotnet development using C#.

```
Install .NET Core.
Install the C# extension from the VS Code Marketplace.
```

Refer: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/dotnet

Refer: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/csharp

Answer (score 0):

While I can see this is a minor problem and rather annoying - VSCode will do this. It's what makes it different to (IE) Visual Studio (Community / Enterprise).

Since I use both I had to look for a solution myself. I currently use the package 'All Autocomplete' by Atishay Jain (https://github.com/atishay/vscode-allautocomplete).

Good luck coding!

Quick edit:
It will still not give you back all options for a class if there's no instance of that class (OO).

Answer (score 0):

I closed VSCode, removed the workspace file and when I re-opened the folder with vscode with it asked me if I wanted to use a particular project file or read all project files in the folder.

Either choice would probably be fine as you will have been so annoyed by this issue, you would not get up to creating a second project :)

Answer (score 0):

I have installed BrackedPairColorizer and when I deleted this extension form VS Code it helps and editor start suggesting code after reload.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, solution for me was downgrading the C# extension from v1.25.0 to v1.24.1

Other versions may also work but this was the first that I tried

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32028228)